# How to use Model's getter Attribute to use in Query Builder

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Described below is my getter in my `Post` model:

```
public function getTicketIdAttribute() {
   return str_pad($this->id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Note that the function simply adds 6 zero padding at the front of the `Post`'s `post_id`.

Now, is it possible to use it in a query builder? Ihave tried the following:

```
Post::where(function($query) use ($keyword) {
   $query->where('detail', 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%')
         ->orWhereHas($query->getTicketIdAttribute(), 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword .'%');
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to have a search engine which look for `Post` object **if**:

1. `$keyword` matches the `Post`'s `detail`

**or**

2. if `$keyword` matches the `getTicketIdAttribute()`

Comment: That's not possible. You have to write an equivalent SQL statement with [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Jonas Staudenmeir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614994/how-to-use-models-getter-attribute-to-use-in-query-builder#comment88240254_50614994) I need to rewrite the code using PHP's `LPAD()`, so:

```
LPAD(id, 6, '0')
```

and to use it in Query Builder I need to apply it using the `DB::raw` method as there is no equivalent `LPAD()` method available right out the box. So, use it like this:

```
DB::raw("LPAD(id, 6, '0')")
```

Just a note that this means for this case the Model's getter Attribute **cannot** be used directly in Query Builder, so need to apply it this way.

Hope this help others, and I thank [Jonas Staudenmeir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614994/how-to-use-models-getter-attribute-to-use-in-query-builder#comment88240254_50614994) for the help.